# Capital share of income and profit margins

Tags: capital, profits, national-accounts, national-income, factor-shares

The capital share of income is defined as gross operating surplus divided by nominal GDP. At the firm level, the profit margin is defined as profits divided by sales. Notwithstanding the fact that gross operating surplus is only an approximate measure of profits, isn't the capital share of income really just an aggregated measure of profit margins?
I mean both the capital share and the firm-level profit margin have profit in the numerator and a measure of income in the denominator. Or am I missing something?